# Borel functional calculus for some spectial operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, functional-calculus

We have the following lemma:
Let $B(H)_s$ be the set of self-adjoint operators on $H$,suppose $\psi :B(H)_s\to B(H)_s$ is a bijective map which preserves commutativity(i.e. $MN=NM$ iff $\psi(MN)=\psi(NM)$),,then there exits an unitary operator or an antinuitary $U$ s.t. for any operator $S\in B(H)_s$,there exists a real-valued bounded Borel function $g_S$ on $\sigma(S)$ s.t $\psi(S)=Ug_S(S)U^*$.

Question:Suppose $\phi $ is a bijective map on $B(H)_{ip}$ which preserves commutativity,where $B(H)_{ip}$ is the set of invertible positive opertaors on $H$.Construct a bijective map $h$ on $B(H)_s$ such that $h(T)=log(\phi(e^T)),\forall T\in B(H)_s$ and preserve commutativity.How to conclude that $\phi(A)=Uf_A(A)U^*,\forall A\in B(H)_{ip}$,where $f_A$ is a real-valued bounded Borel function on $\sigma(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me denote your $h$ by $\psi$. Then, by the lemma,
$$
\log(\phi(e^T)) = \psi(T) = Ug_T(T)U^*
$$
for any $T\in B_s$. Now, let $A\in B_{ip}$ and set $T=\log(A)\in B_s$ as well as $f_A(t) = e^{g_T(\log t)}$. Then
$$
\phi(A) = \phi(e^T) = Ue^{g_T(T)}U^* = Uf_A(A)U^*.
$$

Comment: @math112358 If $A = UBU^*$ with $A,B$ self-adjoint and $U$ unitary, then $f(A) = Uf(B)U^*$ for any bounded measurable $f$. Prove it for polynomials to get the result easily at least for continuous functions.